# How to use Velocity template in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, velocity

In my database i have a table that has records that contain a [velocity](/questions/tagged/velocity) template.
I want to fetch the templates from the database and use it.

Example the table `mydb.myTemplates` has a row with this template:

```
"Hello $name!  Welcome to Velocity!"
```

I want to replace this dynamically as

```
Hello world! Welcome to Velocity!
```

Using [nodes.js](/questions/tagged/nodes.js) I am able to get this template but how can i render it with data?

Answer (score 2):

You can use existing node modules like:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/velocity